# Uninitialized string offset 0 and 1

Tags: php

I got the follow error:

```
verzend mail naar t met attachment: e
verzend mail naar w met attachment: w
verzend mail naar r met attachment: a
verzend mail naar w met attachment: w
verzend mail naar r met attachment: a
verzend mail naar w met attachment: w

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /variables.php on line 248

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in /variables.php on line 248
verzend mail naar met attachment:
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $emailString = 'test@user.nl;www.test.nl^email1@live.nl;www.test2.nl^email3@live.nl;www.test3.nl^';

    $user = explode("^", $emailString); // urls 
    foreach($user as $a_user) {

        $user2 = explode(";", $a_user); // emails
        $a_mailing = array();

        foreach ($user2 as $a_user) {
            $a_mailing[$a_user[0]][] = $a_user[1];
        }   

       foreach($a_mailing as $key => $a_values) {
            foreach($a_values as $value) {
                echo 'verzend mail naar ' . $key . ' met attachment: ' . $value . '<br />';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Which line is the error lines? We can't see line numbers on here.

Comment: i would guess this line:  $a_mailing[$a_user[0]][] = $a_user[1];

Comment: `$a_user` seems to be a string. Don't know what you want to do with `$a_user[0]`. Another problem could be that your are using `$a_user` twice, in the outer `foreach` loop and in the inner one.

Comment: Your code is a mess. `$user2` contains the email address on index 0 and the URL on index 1. Why are you adding all the other `foreach` loops?! I suppose it would be better to rethink a bit what your code should be doing to rewrite it.

Comment: Why `$a_mailing = array();` is in the first foreach, I think you should initialize it outside.

Comment: If you wonder why your question was closed (speaking only for myself): You did not at all explain what your code is supposed to do. You basically just said "this is the code, it does not work as I want, what is wrong?". This requires us to go through your code, trying to understand it, make *assumptions* what you want to do and then create a solution based on these assumptions. That means we have to invest a lot of time just trying to find out what you want to do. SO is not a debugging service. If you had explained your problem properly, I think the question would haven been better received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that $a_user in the first loop is a string. For example.. in the first iteration the $a_user variable contains this: "test@user.nl;www.test.nl";

From what I can see, I believe you are just trying to use the email address as a key and the url as a value so you dont need to use a second loop for that. You can replace:

```
foreach ($user2 as $a_user) {
    $a_mailing[$a_user[0]][] = $a_user[1];
}
```

with:

```
$a_mailing[$user2[0]][] = $user2[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$a_user` is a sting but needs to be an array! You will need to fix that.